# Rewrite URL in Node.js and Express Application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i'm using GET method with a parameter(:slug) to show my post in my website ;

```
app.get('/:slug', function(req, res) {
    var slug = req.param("slug");
    //other codes...
}
```

if i click "domain.com/pink-car" , `app.get('/:slug'` works and response to "pink car" post from mongodb but i also have other GET methods like `/login /admin` , if i enter these ,`app.get('/:slug'` fired again.

So , i think ,if i change my get method to like this;

```
app.get('/posts/:slug', function(req, res) {
}
```

In this time , my url will be "domain.com/posts/pink-car" , but for the SEO , i want to reWrite this url to "domain.com/pink-car" .

What is your suggestions , thank you .

Versions: Node.js - 0.10.33 , Express - 5.0.0-alpha.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to address your basic issue here instead of your specific question. ([What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

As long as your routes are defined in the proper order, it should work. So, first define `/login` and `/admin`, and only then do `/:slug`, and it should all work out fine.

Comment: Firstly , thank you for your quick simple answer , i did not ask too much question but i want to try ask my question with best question pattern , i hope , i can improve myself , thank you.